# Why does a space break validation here?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

In my XML schema, I have created a type named `NonEmptyString`.  It is supposed to reject any value that is null or consists of nothing but whitespace.  I've turned that around to say that it should accept anything that has at least one non-whitespace character.  That should include anything with whitespace between two non-whitespace characters.  However, it is rejecting "BATCH ANNEAL" while accepting "BATCH_ANNEAL".

In case it matters, I'm going to be using this schema in a Python 3 script, although [this XML validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) rejects it as well.

Here is the XML Schema definition:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\S+" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

 <xs:element name="MESSAGE">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:short" name="MESSAGE_NUMBER"/>
      <xs:element type="NonEmptyString" name="MESSAGE_TYPE"/>
      <xs:element type="NonEmptyString" name="PLANT_CODE"/>
      <xs:element type="NonEmptyString" name="PLANT_TEXT"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="TIMESTAMP"/>
      <xs:element type="NonEmptyString" name="SIMULATION_INDEX"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the element I'm trying to validate against it.

```
<MESSAGE>
    <MESSAGE_NUMBER>2601</MESSAGE_NUMBER>
    <MESSAGE_TYPE>MaterialData</MESSAGE_TYPE>
    <PLANT_CODE>ANBA</PLANT_CODE>
    <PLANT_TEXT>BATCH ANNEAL</PLANT_TEXT>
    <TIMESTAMP>2016-03-01T08:54:53</TIMESTAMP>
    <SIMULATION_INDEX>N</SIMULATION_INDEX>
</MESSAGE>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern always must match the *entire* value. `\S+` matches `"BATCH_ANNEAL"` but it does not match `"BATCH ANNEAL"`.

Try

```
<xs:pattern value="\S+|\S.*\S" />
```

to enforce values that either are completely non-whitespace or begin and end with a non-whitespace character. Use something more specific than `.` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think that's a complete enough solution for me, though.  What if there are three or more words?  I tried \S+(\s+\S*)* , which according to pythex.org, matches the entire string "BATCH ANNEAL", but the validator still rejects it.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the word "match" in regular expressions.  From what I've read, a string "matches" a regex if a substring of the string beginning at the start of the string meets the criteria given in the pattern, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the entire string fits those criteria.

Comment: *Usually* that's the case (i.e., usually a pattern can refer to a sub-string), but for validation purposes partial matches are not useful. That's why `<xs:pattern value="foo" />` will test the string against `^foo$`. Three or more words matches the `\S.*\S` part of the `\S+|\S.*\S` compound, I don't think this will be problematic.

Comment: I just tried your string, and it does indeed work.  Thank you very much!  I found an explanation of the regex flavor used in XSD validation here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html .  The portion of the compound that is matched by three words means "A non-space followed by any number of characters followed by a non-space", right?

Comment: It appears that the plus sign is not needed.  I removed the first part of the compound completely, and it worked except when the value was a single character, since the remaining piece of the regex requires at least two characters.  Two characters are accepted.  When I removed the + sign, it still worked.

Comment: Yes, that's completely correct, both comments of yours. The plus sign is really not necessary, but it doesn't hurt, either. You can safely remove it if you want to

Comment: Isn't the pattern `value=".*\S.*"` a rather more obvious way of matching any string of characters containing at least one non-space character?

Comment: @MichaelKay As I understood the OP, the intention was to match values not beginning or ending with a whitespace character.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't see how you derive that requirement from "to reject any value that is null or consists of nothing but whitespace". (I'm assuming "null" here means zero-length.) So in XPath terms the test is `boolean(normalize-space())`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to @Tomalak's (fine, +1) regex-based solution.  This approach uses [`xs:minLength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-minLength) and [`xs:whiteSpace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#rf-whiteSpace) facets instead of an [`xs:pattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-pattern) regex:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
    <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```